# Maddening phenomenon about aiohttp and asyncio

Tags: python, python-asyncio, aiohttp

Below I will use two examples to illustrate this phenomenon:

**example 1:**

```py
import asyncio
import time
import sys
import aiohttp
import threading

async def request():
    print("enter function")
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total = 5)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout= timeout) as session:
        async with session.get("A url that is unreachable on the network") as rsp:
            if rsp.status != 200:
                print("error")
            print("ok")
asyncio.run(request())
```

**example 2:**

```py
import asyncio
import time
import sys
import aiohttp
import threading

def _thread_running_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
    print("loop exit.")

async def request():
    print("enter function")
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total = 5)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout= timeout) as session:
        async with session.get("A url that is unreachable on the network") as rsp:
            if rsp.status != 200:
                print("error")
            print("ok")

loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
thread = threading.Thread(target=_thread_running_loop,args=(loop,))
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(request(), loop)
time.sleep(1000000)
```

**At 'example 1'**, it return 'raise asyncio.TimeoutError' which i expected. But **at 'example 2'**, it's like falling asleep, no response or exception, only printing "enter function".I can't figure out where the problem is, can anyone help.

"**update example 2**"

```py
import asyncio
import time
import sys
import aiohttp
import threading
import logging

def _thread_running_loop(loop):
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    loop.run_forever()
    print("loop exit.")

async def request():
    print("enter function")
    timeout = aiohttp.ClientTimeout(total = 5)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(timeout= timeout) as session:
        async with session.get("A url that is unreachable on the network") as rsp:
            if rsp.status != 200:
                print("error")
            print("ok")

async def call_request():
    try:
        return await request()
    except Exception as e:
        logging.exception(e)

def main():
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    thread = threading.Thread(target=_thread_running_loop,args=(loop,))
    thread.setDaemon(True)
    thread.start()
    while True:
        print("call_request")
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(call_request(), loop)
        asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(call_request(), loop)
        print("wait 100s")
        time.sleep(100)
main()
time.sleep(1000000)
```

Comment: It's not clear what is the meaning of the "updated example 2" from the edit and how it relates to the rest of the question. Does it resolve the problem you had, or does it demonstrate a new one?

Comment: "update example 2" is just my an kind of testing program. It be used to resolve my inner question. Put here as note.

Comment: I still think it's a bad idea to ignore the return value of `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`, but it's ultimately up to you.

Comment: Yeah,you are right. If wait result, they will be synchronous execution.I expect asynchronous and don't care the return value, so i ignore result.

Comment: There is also the option of waiting for both in parallel, and then collecting the results: `fut1 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(...); fut2 = asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(...); asyncio.wait([fut1, fut2]); fut1.result(); fut2.result()`.

Comment: Nice ! I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR you never collect the *result* of the coroutine, so the exception raised in the asyncio thread can't propagate. Add a call to `.result()` and the snippet will work as expected.

> But at 'example 2', it's like falling asleep, no response or exception, only printing "enter function". I can't figure out where the problem is, can anyone help.

It's falling asleep because you've literally told it to fall asleep:

```
time.sleep(1000000)
```

`run_coroutine_threadsafe(a, b)` means "submit coroutine object `a` to run in event loop `b`". By default it doesn't wait for the coroutine to finish because its whole point is to allow your thread to continue doing other things. However, it returns a [`concurrent.futures.Future`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.Future) (not to be confused with `asyncio.Future`) that you can use to check whether the computation is complete, wait for it to complete, and retrieve its result or exception. If you never do any of that, you will never notice the exception because it happens in a completely different thread. But if you do, e.g. by changing the invocation to:

```
asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(request(), loop).result()
```

...you achieve two things: you wait for the coroutine to complete, and the exception raised (if any) propagates to your main thread, making it behave like example 1.

Note that example 1 doesn't really print anything either, it just raises an `InvalidURL` exception, as does example 2 with the above fix.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will test and reply as soon as possible.